# RxJava flatMap with Observable.just() and one argument

Tags: rx-java

I'm using RxJava and I have a problem to understand flatMap.

```
Observable.just(1)
                .flatMap(
                        item -> Observable.just(item + 1),
                        e -> Observable.error(e),
                        () -> Observable.never())
                .subscribe(
                        i -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Got " + i);
                        },
                        e -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "RxJava ERROR", e);
                        });
```

fails with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapNotification$SingleEmitter.offer(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapNotification$1.onNext(OperatorMapNotification.java:82)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7803)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7579)
```

The same code but with 
Observable.just(1,2,3)
just works fine

```
Got 2
Got 3
Got 4
```

Is it a bug or why does RxJava behave differently with just one argument? 
RxJava version is 1.0.13

Comment: Odd. Doesn't happen on 1.0.12. Probably worth reporting as a bug

Comment: Just tested with 1.0.12 and it works...

Comment: Filed a bug https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3180

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with 1.0.13 and 1.0.14. The fix will be available with 1.0.15 (no due date yet).

Comment: So, basically `flatMap` with a source Observable that emits just a single element does not work at the moment? Or is the problem more specific than that?

Comment: This specific `flatMap` overload doesn't work with `just` or other sources that don't support backpressure at the moment.